# Problems with QNetworkAccessManager::deleteResource()

Tags: qt

When you try to delete a file from the server generates an error

```
Error Code:  QNetworkReply::NetworkError(RemoteHostClosedError)
```

Here's the code request

```
    QUrl url2("http://Mysite/pix.png");
    url2.setUserName("*********");
    url2.setPassword("*********");
    url2.setPort(21);

    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    reply = nam->deleteResource(QNetworkRequest(url2));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http and port 21? Or are you accessing an FTP-Server? Note that the documentation says this works for HTTP only:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#deleteResource

Comment: http and port 21, I know that the method only works with http

Comment: I guess you already did, but just to make shure: You enabled deleting on the webserver?

Comment: Well, removing the idea on, because I can delete them using the FTP Manager FileZilla.